# why function reference not live enough?

Tags: rust

I want to make optional reference to function,
and try this:

```
struct Foo {
    cb: Option<&'static Fn(u32)->u32>,
}

fn f1(a: u32) -> u32 { a }

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo{cb: Some(&f1)};
}
```

but compiler report error `borrowed value does not live long enough`, so question:

1. Why `f1` not live long enough?
2. How should I fix this code?